# Log4J debugging is not working?

Tags: java, log4j

I been trying to get the log.debug working in log4j but its not working at all.  below is my source code

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log; 
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class TestLog4J {  
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TestLog4J.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // following logs at FATAL level    
        if (log.isFatalEnabled()) {
            log.fatal("Testing Fatal output");    
        }

        // following logs at ERROR level    
        if (log.isErrorEnabled()) {
            log.error("Testing Error output");
        }

        // following logs at WARN level     
        if (log.isWarnEnabled()) {
            log.warn("Testing Warn output");
        }

        // following logs at INFO level     
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info("Testing Info output");
        }

        // following logs at DEBUG level    
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Testing Debug output");
        }

        // following logs at TRACE level    
        if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
            log.trace("Testing Trace output");    
        }   
    }    
}
```

and here is my log4j.properties... I have a funny feeling that log4f is not finding it.  how can I tell

```
# Global logging configuration
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout


# Console output...
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=[%p,%c{1}] %m%n

# Rolling log file output...
log4j.appender.fileout=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.fileout.File=spring-security-tutorial.log
log4j.appender.fileout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1},%t:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileout.Append=false
```

Comment: if its not found and you are running it from eclipse u'll see 'log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger...'

Comment: Please realize we have *no* idea what is or isn't working. Is `log4j.properties` at the root of your classpath?

Comment: anfy2002us: I think you are right. it may not be getting found

Comment: Dave.. I do have it at the root of my classpath

Comment: Do you have the log4j jar on your classpath? You'll need both the commons-logging jar and the log4j jar for it to look for log4j.properties.

Answer (score 0):

How are you specifying where your `log4j.properties` file is ? The easiest way to see if you're picking up the correct `log4j.properties` is to amend your conversion pattern thus:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=[%p,%c{1}] TEST %m%n
```

and check if your log lines contain the prefix `TEST`.